# Order mysql result by value from JSON_OBJECT

Tags: mysql, sql, json, mariadb, sql-order-by

I have MariaDB 10.2 and this SQL:

```
SELECT products.*,
  CONCAT('[', GROUP_CONCAT(JSON_OBJECT(
  'id', V.id,
  'price', V.price
  ) ORDER BY V.price ASC), ']') AS variants,
FROM products
LEFT JOIN products_variants V ON V.products_id = products.id
GROUP BY products.id
LIMIT 0,10
```

Result is:

```
Array (
  [0] => Array (
    [id] => 1,
    [variants] => [{"id": 1, "price": 100},{"id": 2, "price": 110}]
  )
  [1] => Array (
    [id] => 2,
    [variants] => [{"id": 3, "price": 200},{"id": 4, "price": 210}]
  )
)
```

I need to sort the products according to the price of the first variation of each product.

- Product id 1 must be the first because the first variant price is 100
- Product id 2 must be the second because the first variant price is 200 and 200 > 100

I try:

```
ORDER BY JSON_EXTRACT(`variants`, '$[0].price)
```

but get error:

```
Reference 'variants' not supported (reference to group function)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
order by min(v.price)
```

There is no need to parse the JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of when one should not hide a column (`price`) inside a column (in JSON, in this case).  Instead, keep `price` as its own column to make it simple for MySQL to access for sorting (as you needed) or filtering.

It is OK to also keep the column inside the `JSON` string, so that the JSON is "complete".

The problem was that you had the wrong quotes around `variant`.  Backtics (which you used) is for column and table names.  You needed apostrophes or double-quotes (`'` or `"`) because `variant` is just a string in this context.)